# Replacig text inside multiple repeating patterns in same line

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu, html, markdown

I have something like this;

```
I like reading **books** and taking **notes**
```

I was trying to get something like this;

```
I like reading <b>books</b> and taking <b>notes</b>
```

Tried doing;

```
sed 's/\*\*\(.*\)\*\*/<b>\1<\/b>/g' a.txt
```

This returns;

```
I like reading <b>books** and taking **notes</b>
```

It wraps around the whole line. Any way to get around it?

*note: I'm using a GNU version of sed*

Comment: There are many existing tools to convert markdown to html, including [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [mmark](https://github.com/miekg/mmark) and [markdown_py](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown).   and, of course, [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).   They each have their own quirks and pros and cons, but using any of them is better than wasting time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @cas appreciate the suggestion. I'm pretty new to regex and thought markdown to html conversion using regex would be a good way to get started. I'm having fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following with GNU `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's:\*\*\([^*]*\)\*\*:<b>\1</b>:g' a.txt 
I like reading <b>books</b> and taking <b>notes</b>
```

The `\*\*\([^*]*\)\*\*` pattern captures the string that is between `**...**` that is not a wildcard `*`. Finally you replace the captured group for itself between the tags.

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!